# Why do 82 packages get installed with kde-config-touchpad?

Tags: debian, touchpad, packages

I'm trying to get the touchpad to work correctly on my t61 with debian. I was [advised](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=559339#34) to install kde-config-touchpad to do so.  But when I go to install the package, it comes with 82 different packages:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exiv2 ghostscript kaboom kde-config-touchpad kdebase-runtime
  kdebase-runtime-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools
  libattica0 libclucene0ldbl libexiv2-9 libgraphicsmagick3 libgs8 libilmbase6
  libiodbc2 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdnssd4
  libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4
  libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4
  libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkutils4 libnepomuk4
  libnepomukquery4a libopenexr6 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libphonon4 libplasma3
  libpolkit-qt-1-0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqca2 libqt4-opengl libqt4-svg
  libqt4-webkit libqt4-xmlpatterns libsolid4 libsoprano4 libssh-4
  libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 libwmf0.2-7
  libxcb-shape0 libxine1 libxine1-bin libxine1-console libxine1-ffmpeg
  libxine1-misc-plugins libxine1-plugins libxine1-x libxml2-utils libxss1
  odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 oxygen-icon-theme phonon-backend-xine
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon
  ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-extra virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
```

Why is all of this necessary just for getting my touchpad to work when I tap it?

Comment: Do you have kde on the touchpad?

Answer (score 2):

These packages are necessary for the KDE framework. There are probably other ways to get your touchpad to work, but if you want to try it this way these packages need to be installed.

For example the ttf-dejavu and ttf-dejavu-extra are fonts for your KDE applications, the libk*-packages are libraries that provide functions for KDE applications etc. Once you installed these packages you could install other KDE packages that could make use of these libraries as well.

Comment: your exactly right.